# How to select an href class tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How can I select a href class tag?

Example of html code:

```
<a title="bla" class="example"> text </a>
```

So I wish to identify which a tag to grab from via either "title" or "class" then output the text within the a tags, so in this case output would be

```
text
```

Code I'm using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://www.example.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for profile in soup.select(" select input here "):

    print(profile.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: `a.find_all('a', {'title': 'bla'})` or `a.find_all('a', {'class': 'example'})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from what @Stack suggested in comments:

```
soup.find_all('a', {'title': 'bla'})
soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'example'})
```

You can do that using [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) (I even see that you already have that `select()` call there:

```
soup.select("a[title=bla]")
soup.select("a.example")
```